# clojure quotes and tilde in macros

Tags: macros, clojure, lisp, quoting

I am new to Clojure and I am having trouble understanding its quoting system. I am writing a macro and I have made two similar cases - one works, the other doesn't. In a sense, I am just trying to surround my statement with try/catch condition.

Here's the code that works:

```
(defmacro safe
  [arg1 arg2]
  (list 'let arg1 arg2)
)
```

Here's the code that doesn't work

```
(defmacro safe
    [arg1 arg2]
    '(try
        ~(list 'let arg1 arg2)
        (catch Exception e (str "Error: " (.getMessage e)))
    )
)
```

after the `~` symbol, it should escape the quotes, but for some reason, it seems like it doesn't. The Error is: "Unable to resolve symbol: arg1 in this context...".

Thanks for your help!

---

Edit:

Code that I call the macro with:

```
(println (safe [s (new FileReader (new File "text.txt"))] (.read s)))
```

Also, I import this:

```
(import java.io.FileReader java.io.File)
```

Goal is to read first symbol from a file, while being safe from incorrect text file names. This is my school assignment by the way, so I should not use any other way to do it and the macro has to be called like that, I know about the `with-open`, etc.

Comment: What do you wish your macro to do?

Comment: **Corrected:** `macroexpand` is very useful for debugging macros. For example, `(macroexand '(safe2 [s (new FileReader (new File "text.txt"))] (.read s)))`  You may want to `pprint` the result.

Comment: you'd better name the macro `with-safe` as a convention ;)

Answer (score 11):

Escaping (`~`) only works with quasi-quote (also known as syntax quote).  You need to use the "back-quote" (`` ` ``, found on the same key as `~` on most US keyboards), not the normal single-quote (`'`, which is on the same key as `"`).  It's a subtle difference graphically, which can be easy to miss.

You can also get rid of the `list` by not quoting the `let` and un-quoting `arg1` and `arg2`.  With these changes, we get something like this:

```
`(try ;; note back-quote, not regular quote.
    (let ~arg1 ~arg2) ;; Getting rid of list — not necessary, but most find this more readable
    (catch Exception e (str "Error: " (.getMessage e))))
```

Now, if we check our progress using `macroexpand`:

```
(macroexpand '(safe2 [s (new FileReader (new File "text.txt"))] (.read s)))
```

We get the following:

```
(try (clojure.core/let [s (new FileReader (new File text.txt))]
       (.read s))
     (catch java.lang.Exception user/e
       (clojure.core/str Error: (.getMessage user/e))))
```

You might notice that in Clojure, quasi-quoted symbols are resolved when the macro is compiled.  Symbols that can't be resolved are qualified with the current namespace (`user` in this case).  The rationale for this is that it helps you write "hygienic" macros.  In this case, however, we don't want to resolve the `e` symbol, because local variables can't be given a qualified name.

We have a few options now.  The first is to basically forgo hygiene.  That works in this case, since you aren't expanding any user-provided code inside the `catch` block.  So there isn't any way the name `e` could conflict with a user variable.  This solution would look like this:

```
`(try
    (let ~arg1 ~arg2)
    (catch Exception ~'e (str "Error: " (.getMessage ~'e))))
```

Note the use of `~'e` instead of just `e`.  The `~` is to escape from the quasi-quote, then we use a regular quote to quote `e`.  It looks a little weird, but it works.

While the above solution works, it's arguably better to use a generated symbol instead of `e`.  That way, if you ever change your macro to accept user-provided code for the `catch` block, you can be sure it will still work.  In this particular case, an "auto-generated" symbol fits the bill perfectly.  This looks as follows:

```
`(try
    (let ~arg1 ~arg2)
    (catch Exception e# (str "Error: " (.getMessage e#))))
```

Basically, whenever the Clojure reader encounters a symbol with a trailing `#` inside a quasi-quote form, it will produce a new `gensym`'d symbol and replace every occurence of that symbol (i.e., `e#`) with the `gensym`'d one.  If we `macroexpand` this, we would get something like:

```
(try (clojure.core/let [s (new FileReader (new File text.txt))]
       (.read s))
     (catch java.lang.Exception e__66__auto__ 
       (clojure.core/str Error: (.getMessage e__66__auto__))))
```

As you can see, every occurence of `e#` was replaced with a machine-generated symbol.  Here `e__66__auto__` is the auto-gen'd symbol.

Finally, while auto-gen is convenient, it is not always sufficient.  The main issue is that, since auto-gen'd symbols are produced at *read* time, every *evaluation* of the quasi-quote form (i.e., *expansion* of the macro) will use the same auto-gen'd symbols.  In this paricular case, that's fine.  However, there are cases where this can lead to conflicts if, for example, nested macro forms are used.  In these cases, it is necessary to use an explicitly `gensym`'d symbol every time the macro is expanded.  With this approach, the body of your macro would look like this:

```
(let [e (gensym)]
  `(try
     (let ~arg1 ~arg2)
     (catch Exception ~e (str "Error: " (.getMessage ~e)))))
```

Here `e` is a local variable in your macro, whose value is the a fresh symbol (via `gensym`).  In the quasi-quote, we must escape `e` in order to use that `gensym`'d value.

If we expand this, we would get something like:

```
(try (clojure.core/let [s (new FileReader (new File text.txt))]
       (.read s))
     (catch java.lang.Exception G__771 
       (clojure.core/str Error: (.getMessage G__771))))
```

If we expand this again, we would find `G__771` replaced by a different symbol (perhaps G__774).  In contrast, the auto-gen'd solution (`e#`) would always use the same symbol for every expansion (at least until we recompile the macro).

Hopefully this gives you a better understanding of macros, symbols, and hygiene.  Let me know if anything isn't clear.

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, it produces a new error ("Can't bind qualified name:user/e, compiling.."). I updated my question with the code that I am calling the macro with, maybe it will be easier to test, thanks again!

Comment: See the comment I left on the question regarding `macroexpand`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to quote the `println` form in my `macroexpand` example.  You need to quote the input to `macroexpand` in this case, since it is a regular function, in order to prevent it from being evaluated first.

Comment: Also, you want to macroexpand the `safe` form, not the `println` form.  I posted a new comment with a corrected `macroexpand` invocation.

Comment: does using a gensym name like `e#` instead of `e` work?

Comment: macroexpand returned this:
`(try (clojure.core/let [s (new FileReader (new File text.txt))] (.read s)) (catc
h java.lang.Exception e__66__auto__ (clojure.core/str Error:  (.getMessage user/
e))))`

Comment: It looks like you replace `e` with an auto-gen'd symbol (`e#`) in one place, but not the other?  At any rate, see my update for an explanation of what's going on and ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There’s two problems here:

First, unsplicing (`~` and `~@`) work only inside syntax-quote (`` ` ``). Syntax quote is usually chosen for macros because it also does symbol namespace resolution at macro definition place. Simple quote (`'`) will keep symbols intact, so ns resolution will happen at macro invocation site. Because you do not control where and how your macro will be called, it might be very confusing.

Second, you cannot just declare new symbols in quoted code, it may cause name conflict with code around macro. Each new symbol introduced by macro should use suffix `#` so Clojure macroexpansion will replace it with new autogenerated name that cannot cause any name conflicts with user code.

```
(defmacro m []
 `(let [x# 1]
    x#))

(macroexpand-1 '(m)) =>

=> (clojure.core/let [x__6257__auto__ 1]
     x__6257__auto__)
```

Note how `let` became fully-qualified `clojure.core/let` (avoiding ns resolution nuances later), and `x#` got replaced with `x__6257__auto__` (avoiding name conflicts).

Your code should be written as this:

```clj
(defmacro safe [arg1 arg2]
 `(try
    (let ~arg1 ~arg2)
      (catch Exception e#
        (str "Error: " (.getMessage e#)))))
```

Check like this:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(safe [s (new FileReader (new File "text.txt"))] (.read s)))

↓↓↓

(try
  (clojure.core/let [s (new FileReader (new File "text.txt"))]
    (.read s))
  (catch java.lang.Exception e__6283__auto__
    (clojure.core/str "Error: " (.getMessage e__6283__auto__))))
```

I would also recommend using idiomatic names for macro args and make second argument of arbitrary length:

```clj
(defmacro safe-let [bindings & body]
 `(try
    (let ~bindings
      ~@body)
      (catch Exception e#
        (str "Error: " (.getMessage e#)))))
```